# Click Event open new blade page {{$data->title}}

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm pulling data from database and i would like to make `{{$data->title}}` clickable.

“This for a new server. In the past, I’ve tried on existing servers.”

```
@foreach($ress as $key => $data)

{{$data->title}}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Have a button or a hyperlink.

Comment: What would like to happen when someone cliks the title?

Comment: open new page with post details

Comment: Then you should look at @timw answer.

Comment: im having trouble defining a variable route depending on title , as it will be slug for seo

Comment: dynamic ive ment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a route in your `routes.php` and call it in your template

```
<a href="{{ route('route-name', $data->id) }}">{{ $data->title }}</a>
```

Comment: Could you hint me with route defining i am junior developer first time in laravel

Comment: As route is variable depending on title

Comment: dynamic ive ment

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do it. You can change the variable names to the ones you have used in your code.

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/show/{id}','DataController@show')->name('showdata);
```

Link on say **dataindex.blade.php**

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
 <a href="{{ route('showdata', $data->id) }}">{{ $data->title }}</a>
@endforeach
```

**DataController.php**

```
public function show(){
 $datas = DB::table('table_name')->get();
 return view('dataindex', ['datas'=>$datas]);
```

}